# Find all keys JSON - RapidJSON

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I need to find all the keys in the kTypeNames[] with rapidJSON library.
Trying to iterate all the nodes but I'm missing something; here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"

using namespace rapidjson;

using namespace std;

const char* kTypeNames[] = { "id", "text", "templ_text", "key" };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

string line;
char json[65000];
std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
unsigned long i = 0;
if (file.is_open()) {
    while (!file.eof()) {
        file.get(json[i]);
        i++;
    }
    file.close();
} else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}

Document document;
document.Parse(json);
printf("\n\n\n\n*********Access values in document**********\n");

assert(document.IsObject());

for (auto Typename : kTypeNames) {
    if (document.HasMember(Typename)) {

        cout << "\n";
        cout << Typename << ":" << document[Typename].GetString()<< endl;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n None\n";
    }
 }
```

It does not works with a nested JSON.

```
{
"node": {
    "text": "find this",
    "templ_text": "don't find",
    "ver": "don't find"
},
"ic": "",
"text": "also this",
"templ_text": "don't care",
"par": {
    "SET": {
        "vis": "<blabla>",
        "text": "keyFound",
        "templ_text": "don't need this"
    }
}
}
```

This is the output:

```
None
text:also this
templ_text:don't care
None
```

I would like to find all the "text" keys
How can I iterate through all the nodes/ json document?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is just searching for a list of pre-defined keys directly within the document root (`document.HasMember` is not a recursive search!).

You could just loop through the document nodes recursively. For example for object/map nodes, you loop on the `MemberBegin()` and `MemberEnd()` iterators, similar to a `std::map` or other standard containers.

```
for (auto i = node.MemberBegin(); i != node.MemberEnd(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "key: " << i->name.GetString() << std::endl;
    WalkNodes(i->value);
}
```

Array uses `Begin()` and `End()`. Then, when you encounter a node with a "text" member, you can output the value of that node (`i->value`).

Alternatively, rather than using a `Document` DOM object, you can do it with the parser stream. Rapidjson uses a "push" API for this, where it calls methods you define in a class as it encounters each piece of JSON. Specifically, it will call a `Key` method.

```
class MyHandler : public BaseReaderHandler<UTF8<>, MyReader> {
    bool Key(const char* str, SizeType length, bool copy)
    {
        std::cout << "Key: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    ...
};
MyHandler handler;
rapidjson::Reader reader;
rapidjson::StringStream ss(json);
reader.Parse(ss, handler);
```

This gets a bit more complex, you will want to set a flag of some sorts, and then output the next value callback after.

```
class MyHandler : public BaseReaderHandler<UTF8<>, MyReader> {
    bool Key(const char* str, SizeType length, bool copy)
    {
        isTextKey = strcmp(str, "text") == 0; // Also need to set to false in some other places
        return true;
    }
    bool String(const char* str, SizeType length, bool copy)
    {
        if (isTextKey) std::cout << "text string " << str << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    ...

    bool isTextKey = false;
};
```

Also remember, that JSON allows a null within a string `\0`, which is why also have the size parameters and members, as well as Unicode. So to fully support any JSON document that needs accounting for.